# UIViewController Subclass does not recognize UITapGesture

Tags: ios, swift

With the intention to slim down my viewcontroller a little bit, i want to move the ui elements and corresponding functions into a subclass. but then my gestures don't work. how can i solve this?

**MyViewController.swift**

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        SubclassMyViewController().setupUserInterface(view: view)
    }

    @objc func doSomething() {
        log.info("logo was tapped")
    }

 }
```

**SubclassMyViewController.swift**

```swift
class SubclassMyViewController: MyViewController {

    func setupUserInterface(view: UIView) {
        // ...
        view.addSubview(logoImage)
        logoImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        logoImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        logoImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true        

    }

    lazy var logoImage: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "logo")

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        // ADD GESTURE 
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doSomething))
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        return imageView
    }()
}
```

Putting everything into the Viewcontroller does work. if I split it in two classes, the gesture won't be recognized.. Thanks!

Comment: What is the class of your controller in storyboard?

Comment: never used storyboard, doing all programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing some things here.

`SubclassMyViewController().setupUserInterface(view: view)` this line creates an instance of `SubclassMyViewController`, which in your code sample owns the image view. Because you don't have any references to the created subclass however, it will die as soon as this line is done executing.

You could accomplish your goal by creating a static helper class instead. Here's how that would look.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        MyViewControllerSetupHelper.setupUserInterface(viewController: self)
    }

    @objc func doSomething() {
        log.info("logo was tapped")
    }

}

class MyViewControllerSetupHelper {

    static func setupUserInterface(viewController: MyViewController) {
        let view = viewController.view!

        let imageView = getLogoImageView()
        viewController.imageView = imageView

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: viewController, action: #selector(MyViewController.doSomething))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        view.addSubview(imageView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5)
        ])
    }

    static func getLogoImageView() -> UIImageView {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "logo")
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        return imageView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`SubclassMyViewController().setupUserInterface(view: view)` is creating a new instance of subclass, but the reference of the instance is not stored.

Swift will deallocate the class if there is no reference (refer to [ARC](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)).

The lazy var `logoImage` is adding a GestureRecognizer which points to the `doSomething()` of the SubclassMyViewController-instance, which is deallocated immediately.

It would work if you do this (THIS IS NOT GOOD):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var x: SubclassMyViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        x = SubclassMyViewController()
        x.setupUserInterface(view: view)
    }

    @objc func doSomething() {
        log.info("logo was tapped")
    }

}
```

You should fix your design, because:

- ViewController is accessing SubclassMyViewController, which is, however, a subclass of ViewController

Comment: sounds logical, so I shouldn't be forming a subclass for this.

Comment: @TyrusRechs That's correct. You had it right before you split them up. UIViewController subclasses do frequently become pretty large and you'll kinda just have to live with that. A nice way to shorten them is to create subclasses for your views instead of setting them up inline, for example by making a `LogoImageView: UIImageView` class.

Answer (score 0):

You doing really strange things. Gesture recognizer added to `SubclassMyViewController` instance. Which seams removed after creation.

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        SubclassMyViewController().setupUserInterface(view: view, vc: self)
    }

    @objc func doSomething() {
        log.info("logo was tapped")
    }

}


class SubclassMyViewController: MyViewController {

    func setupUserInterface(view: UIView, vc: UIViewController) {
        // ...
        view.addSubview(logoImage)
        logoImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        logoImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        logoImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true        

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: vc, action: #selector(doSomething))
        logoImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        logoImage.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    lazy var logoImage: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "logo")

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        return imageView
    }()
}
```

P.S. code is really dirty.. don't do like this

**Edit**

Probably this is what you wanna do:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        SubclassMyViewController().setupUserInterface(view: view, vc: self)
    }

    @objc func doSomething() {
        log.info("logo was tapped")
    }

    func setupUserInterface(view: UIView) {
        // ...
        view.addSubview(logoImage)
        logoImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        logoImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        logoImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true        

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doSomething))
        logoImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        logoImage.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    lazy var logoImage: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "logo")

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        return imageView
    }()
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this works! What exactly do you mean the code is pretty dirty?

Comment: @TyrusRechs 1) You create some other instance witch delete instantly. 2) You doing inheritance, but not using it. With a little peace of knowledge about project it looks dirty.